# How to display an info "live" on a website?

Tags: php, html

I made an HTML code which display this:

Up:0

Down:0

Left:0

Right:0

When I press one of the arrow, the "0" changes for a "1" for as long as I hold it.

My problem now is that, being HTML, if I press an arrow, the "1" will display only for me. How can I make it so anybody on the page can see it/change it?

I know that I will probably need to use another language, but which one and which part of the code de you think I'll need to modify?  I was thinking of using PHP.

Thanks a lot,

Philippe

Comment: Firstly, you haven't provided any code, second, its nowhere near as easy to do as this question makes out. There's no copy and paste, you have a fair amount of research and learning ahead of you if you want to achieve this. I vote to close as it won't help you or any of the people that land on this page. Try to find out more and then post a question when you get stuck on actually writing the code.

Comment: it is not as simple as changing the language... you need to send the information to the server (javascript), get the information in the server (php is an option), store the information somewhere in the server (database, file), and then the other instances of your browser need to poll the server for changes.

Comment: The question is IMHO totally valid but should be moved to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Perhaps look at something like [Meteor](http://meteor.com/), but a question like this, here, is going to get closed without addressing a specific problem.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you want. There are different ways.

If this is for some kind of game and you need live interaction you might take a look at [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). But they're pretty new, so old browsers wont support them.

If a more "slow" way is possible send an [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) request on key down, on the server side flag whatever you have there, your db record, so that "up" becomes 1. On key up send another request and record "up" = 0;

When somebody else accesses the page read the values from the db. To keep the changes up to date you might want to use something like [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling).

See also:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOSH

Based on your negative voting (at this time -2) and the comment(s) and my personal opinion about your question I'm pretty sure you're a beginner. So you might want to learn Javascript as well and become skilled in php as well.

What you want involves two programming languages ([Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), php - HTML is NOT a programming language) and several technological concepts. This is not a newbie task you want to do. So start smart, start small.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a database (MySQL) to save the updates on server so other clients can access them. You can do this using ajax. Use ajax to send the data to your server (using PHP). Then use ajax again to get any new updates from the server and update other clients.

Note: if you use this method it won't be in sync with other users. Meaning there will be a delay when the data transfers between the user and server and other clients. you need to do ajax checks every half a second or something to get latest data from the server..

This is just 1 way of how to do such thing. so you need (PHP to process the data in the server, MySQL to save your updates in database, ajax to make connection between all of the clients and the server).